# Chunk Generation Performance in C#

Tags: c#, performance, optimization

I'm working on a game in C#, this game generate new chunk (infinite) when you move around.
If have in my list > 1000 chunks it become laggy but I only load the necessary chunks on my screen. Tried all things to improve the code but nothing new :S.

```
Stopwatch ChunkDetect = new Stopwatch();
public readonly int sizeChunk = 800;

    private void loadChunks()
    {
        ChunkDetect.Restart();
        ChunkDetect.Start();
        int CamXCh = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(-Convert.ToDouble(CameraX) / sizeChunk)),
            CamYCh = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(-Convert.ToDouble(CameraY) / sizeChunk));

        int sizeX = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(gameBox.Width) / sizeChunk)) + 4,
            sizeY = Convert.ToInt32(Math.Ceiling(Convert.ToDouble(gameBox.Height) / sizeChunk)) + 4;

        Random generation = new Random();
        // Load Chunks or Create
        for (int chunkX = 0; chunkX < sizeX; chunkX++)
        {
            for (int chunkY = 0; chunkY < sizeY; chunkY++)
            {
                int xChunk = chunkX + CamXCh - 2,
                    yChunk = chunkY + CamYCh - 2;

                Chunks currentChunk = allChunks.Where(i => i.positionX == xChunk && i.positionY == yChunk).FirstOrDefault();

                bool isLoad = true;
                if (chunkX == 0 || chunkX == (sizeX - 1) || chunkY == 0 || chunkY == (sizeY - 1))
                    isLoad = false;

                if (currentChunk == null)
                {
                    Color ColorBiome = Color.FromArgb(64, 233, 56);
                    string BiomeName = "Grass";
                    allChunks.Add(new Chunks(xChunk, yChunk, sizeChunk, ColorBiome, BiomeName, isLoad, 40));
                }
                else
                {
                    bool isCurrentLoaded = currentChunk.isLoaded;
                    if (!isLoad)
                        currentChunk.isLoaded = false;
                    else if (!isCurrentLoaded)
                        currentChunk.isLoaded = true;
                }
            }
        }
        ChunkDetect.Stop();
    }
```

Comment: So what is your actual question? Keep in mind StackOverflow is not a code optimisation service.

Comment: Even if it were, this method doesn't tell anyone much of anything.

Comment: Hey user please learn how to use a profiler only then you will be able to determine what is the cause for the lagging.  Also you can ask about code optimization in coderevoew.

Comment: What type is `allChunks`? You appear to be doing a linear search to find any matching chunks when using an array or dictionary lookup would be far faster.

Comment: Mi  question is about, its easier to make a linq like                Chunks currentChunk = allChunks.Where(i => i.positionX == xChunk && i.positionY == yChunk).FirstOrDefault(); or and diccionary or bidimensional array with cords x and y?